# empty data frame returned with row_number== value more than present in the data frame

Tags: r, dplyr

How can I make dplyr filter verb to print "NA" when row_number > 10 (number of rows in the data frame) instead of returning empty data frame?

Example:

```
library(dplyr)

df<-data.frame(x=1:10)

filter(df,row_number()==11)
```

execution of lines above returns:

```
[1] x

<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

I am hoping to get "NA" as an output

Comment: It would seem that you would have to override the behavior of the R filter function.

Comment: IMO such behavior would imply that there is an 11th observation in your data that happens to have a missing value which is not correct. Therefore I think this wouldn't make much sense normally. Can you explain why you want such behavior?

Comment: And as a side note, such filter statement would be easier (and probably faster) with `slice(11)` because slice takes an index.